# Unable to import Reactjs Class for testing with mocha and enzyme

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

**My test file's code is:**

```
var React = require('react');
var {shalow} = require('enzyme')
var {SearchBox} = require('../static/js/functions')
var expect = require('expect');

describe('Test', function(){
  it('1', function(){
    expect(true).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

**This is my React class in functions.js**

```
var SearchBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchList data={this.props.data}></SearchList>
        <li>
          <button id="previous_page" className="previous_page" onClick={back}>Previous</button>
          <button id="next_page" className="next_page" onClick={next}>Next</button>
        </li>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

It is working fine but I want to write tests and when I run it, it outputs the following error :

> irtza@irtza-Lenovo-G50-70:~/Desktop/Kamal Hasan/pedialink$ mocha
>   ./js_test/*.js
>   **/home/irtza/Desktop/Kamal Hasan/pedialink/static/js/functions.js:39
>                               ,
>                               ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>       at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)**
>       at Module._compile (module.js:511:25)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:466:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (/home/irtza/Desktop/Kamal Hasan/pedialink/js_test/test.js:3:19)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:466:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:220:27
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Mocha.loadFiles (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:217:14)
>       at Mocha.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:485:10)
>       at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:405:18)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
>       at startup (node.js:159:18)
>       at node.js:444:3

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a mix between ES5 and ES6 syntax.

I think that the problem come from this portion of code :

```js
var React = require('react');
var {shalow} = require('enzyme');
var {SearchBox} = require('../static/js/functions');
```

If you wanna use ES5 syntax :

```js
var React = require('react');
var shalow = require('enzyme').shalow; // notice how we access object property `.objectProperty`
var SearchBox = require('../static/js/functions');
```

If you wanna use ES6 syntax :

```js
import React from 'react';
import {shalow} form 'enzyme'; // notice how we access object property `{objectProperty}` 
import SearchBox form '../static/js/functions';
```

also make sure at the end of your function.js file, you export the component with :

```js
module.exports = SearchBox; // ES5 syntax
export default SearchBox; // ES6 syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update Node (mocha is depending on node.js) version (to support es6 modules) or export your component using requireJS - module.exports ... + You should check what parts of es6 your node version supports, because code passed to mocha is not "babelized" :)

Comment: Check: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ if you are not using unsupported parts of JS. Plus what are next and back (passed to onClick)? Are the defined anywhere?